# Calculate smallest number of days for a number of tasks to finish.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have the following optimization exercise:    
 
A project requires the following jobs *A*, *B*, *C*,
*D*, *E*, *F* and *G* to be done. The spending time (by day) for each job is *pA = 4*, *pB = 2*, *pC = 6*,
*pD = 7*, *pE = 9*, *pF = 6* and *pG = 2*, respectively.

---

*X1 + X2 + ... + Xn <= Y1 + Y2 + ... + Ym + c*  
 
 
Note that all jobs ***Xi (i = 1,..., n)*** need to be completed c days before starting the jobs **Yk (k =
1, ... , m)**. We start the project at date 0. We “finish” the project when all of its jobs will be
completed.

---

My question is:
 Suppose that: *A <= B + C + D; B + C <= D; C <= E + G; E <= F*. Which is the earliest day that
the project will finish?

  A. 28
  B. 36
  C. 2
  D. 25

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you work on multiple jobs at the same time?

Comment: It seems that $c=0$. So the answer is $4+6+9+6=25$.